# Why is the intersection of a clopen set and another set clopen in this proof?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a proof that the union of pairwise non-disjoint connected sets is connected. So we let $W_\alpha$ be the connected sets in question and $W = \bigcup_{\alpha}W_\alpha$. Now we suppose that $F$ is a non-empty clopen subset of $W$ (we want to show that $F = W$). So, for some $\alpha_0, F \cap W_{\alpha_0}$ is non-empty, and apparently itself clopen, from which the intersection must equal $W_{\alpha_0}$ and the proof follows shortly after. I, however, can't see how it follows that the intersection is clopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F\cap W_{\alpha_0}$ may well not be clopen in the whole space, but it’s clopen in the subspace topology on $W_{\alpha_0}$. Since $W_{\alpha_0}$ is connected in its subspace topology, and $F\cap W_{\alpha_0}\ne\varnothing$, it follows that $F\cap W_{\alpha_0}=W_{\alpha_0}$.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but isn't any subset of $W_{\alpha_0}$ clopen in the subspace topology?

Comment: @Kannaguchi: Not at all: $W_{\alpha_0}$ is connected, so its only clopen subsets in the subspace topology are itself and $\varnothing$.

Comment: Oooooh, sorry, I misread. Any subset is clopen in **its** subspace topology, but certainly not in the subspace topology of $W_{\alpha_0}$.  I managed to confuse myself with subsets and subspaces.